# Can we connect few models of a Rails 3 app to different type of database using the ActiveRecord adapter?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

Let there is a rails 3 app with two models, a Project and Notification using the ActiveRecord adapter with MySql.

Project has various states using state_machine and when its state changes, I want the notifications to be stored and retrieved back using MongoDb?

Can this be done using rails3?

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord is for SQL driven databases, at least you can use ActiveModel and build some custom logic to handle MongoDb.

alternatively, you can use specific MongoDB adapters:
[MongoMapper](http://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper) or
[Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/)

Comment: Since AR is also implemented on the ActiveModel's API, Can I use the Mongoid/MongoMapper just for a single/two models??

Comment: why not? when you put files in app/models/ rails will look for models there. so you can have models derived from other classes, not necessarily AR or AM.